# how to categorize tables in php using arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im new to PHP. Im creating songbook.

Question 1 : I want to create tables which consists the list of songs alphabetically.  I dont want to create A.php, B.php, C.php for every alphabet. I have no idea how to do that. I know how to create a table with array.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $song; ?>
    </td>
    <td><a href="publicsearch.php?lyric=<?php echo $song; ?>"><?php echo $lyric["title"]; ?></a>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $lyric["artist"]; ?>
    </td>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Question 2:
I want to create a table which shows the results of the same artist in another table.

```
////Arrays/////

   /////song 197 -  artist jackson////

"197"         => array(

"title"    => "a song with a id - 197",


"chords"    => " ....",

"artist"    => "jackson ",                        

"tags"    => "unknown "

),


   /////song 210 - with same artist jackson////


"210"         => array(

"title"    => "another song with different id - 210 in other table",


"chords"    => " ....",

"artist"    => "jackson",                        

"tags"    => "unknown "

),
```

Pls help me out.

Comment: What you're looking for here is effectively using `$_GET` arguments in your links. I'd advise against going too far down this road, though, low-level PHP can get messy in a hurry. What's better is to use a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that will give you a  router, something that handles mapping various "pages" like this without having to create a ridiculous number of files.

Comment: @tadman The guy cleary doesn't even know (properly) what `$_GET` is and you're telling him to get his hands on a framework? Let him make mistakes and learn.

Comment: @Linesofcode That attitude is not very productive, like telling someone to learn to fly by jumping off a bridge repeatedly. Laravel, as an example, has lots of examples that cover this sort of thing out of the box. It's exceptionally beginner friendly.

Comment: Yeah right..try to talk about models, class's or MVC pattern to a guy who has no clue how to create a correct array.

Comment: @Linesofcode Many people learn best by examples, and Laravel has *many* to start with. These can easily be adapted to the problem at hand here without having to know much about MVC or otherwise. That can all be tackled incrementally, it's not as big as deal as you're going on about. People can learn, and it's a lot easier to learn from good examples than by bashing around with the core PHP functions with no direction at all other than your advice to "make mistakes and learn".

Comment: No. Laravel (as all the others frameworks) doesn't teach you the basics of PHP. It's not their goal and will never be. In order to understand any PHP framework you need some basic knowledges.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89413/discussion-between-tadman-and-linesofcode).

Comment: Im a front end developer. I just starting learning php few days back. I need to develop this site urgently. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe instead of looking into a PHP framework/library you should try to connect to a database like MySql, MS-SQL or PostGresql. A solution based on a static PHP array will not be easily editable.